# Auditing Success and Failure event to folder

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, windows-10, audit

I'm using PowerShell to add users to auditing for folders in Windows 10.
I'm using this code to set "EVERYONE" for Auditing.
But I need to do special rules for fail and special rules for Success and Fail, so I need it to save in 2 different lines.  - like this picture:

[image: auditing]

This is the code I'm using:

```
$Folders = "C:\windows\system32\config"

Foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    Write-Host "" # Empty line
    Write-Host "Applying Auditing for folder", $Folder
    Write-Host "" # Empty line

    $ACL = Get-Acl $Folder

    # Set Auditing for Success event for above Folders for EVeryone group
    $PermAudited = "CreateFiles"
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule("Everyone", $PermAudited, "Failure")
    $ACL.SetAuditRule($AccessRule)

    # Set Auditing for Success event for Top folder
    Write-Host $Folder, "for auditing Success event"
    $ACL | Set-Acl $Folder
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question here. Does something not work the way you expected? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Specify those rules using the `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights` enum, Check the available rules like this:

```
[enum]::GetNames([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights])
```

Basically you need to take a look on one of the Constructors for the [FileSystemAuditRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemauditrule(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand how you need to set it, for your needs I think this is the right one:

```
FileSystemAuditRule(
string identity,
FileSystemRights fileSystemRights,
AuditFlags flags
)
```

So, you need to set `Rights` and `AuditFlags`, based on your example it should be something like this:

```
$Rights = "ReadAndExecute","Modify"
$Flags = "Failure"

$AccessRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]$Rights 
$AuditFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.AuditFlags]$Flags
```

Then Set the ACL like this:

```
$ACL = Get-Acl $Folder
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule("Everyone",$AccessRights, $AuditFlags)
$ACL.SetAuditRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl -Path $Folder -AclObject $ACL
```